# what's the difference between a.append(b) with a.append(b[:]) in Python

Tags: python, arraylist

Let's assume that `a = []` and `b = [1,2,3,4]`, if I use `a.append(b)`, when some changes happend to b, a will change too. But if I use `a.append(b[:])`, a will not change when b changes.

Actually I don't understand what happends behind this.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list). The first appends a reference to `b` to `a`, while the second makes a new list which is a copy of `b` and then appends that list to `a`.

Comment: @Brian yes! thanks so much!

Comment: `b[:]` is one way to create a copy of a `list` (or other sequence-like objects, like `tuple` or `str`). You could also just say `b.copy()` and it would be equivalent.